# hibernate JPA composite foreign key issue on read

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, hibernate-mapping

I am using Hibernate JPA, EnterpriseDB(PostgresPlus Advanced Server 9.2.1.3) and Jboss 7.1.1 Final and receiving an exception while reading an entity with composite primary key and (one-to-one) foreign key link to another entity.

I have prepared a project to show the case. Click [here](http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=gd0fd69b2f711a54d99927268484a959b3995590a2) to download the example project file.
Note: The file will be available on the server for the next 7 days. If required, I can upload the file and change the link.

I try to read entity list, matching one of the columns of composite primary key with a parameter.

```
public List<TableA> getComposites(String key) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<TableA> query = cb.createQuery(TableA.class);

    Root<TableA> aEntity = query.from(TableA.class);
    aEntity.fetch(TableA_.tableB, JoinType.LEFT);

    query.where(cb.equal(aEntity.get(TableA_.id).get(TableAPK_.colA), key));

    query.select(aEntity).distinct(true);

    try {
        return em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    } catch (NoResultException ignore) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Exception is this:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class org.test.hibernate.persistence.entity.TableB. Expected: class org.test.hibernate.persistence.entity.TableBPK, got class org.test.hibernate.persistence.entity.TableAPK
```

Table A and Table B have one to one link with composite primary key (col_a, col_b, col_c), sharing same column names. Table B's primary key is also foreign key to Table A's primary key.

```
@Embeddable
public class TableAPK implements Serializable {
//default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(name="col_a")
private String colA;

@Column(name="col_b")
private String colB;

@Column(name="col_c")
private String colC;


@Entity
@Table(name="table_a")
public class TableA implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private TableAPK id;

@Column(name="col_ex_d")
private String colExD;

//bi-directional one-to-one association to TableB
@OneToOne(mappedBy="tableA", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private TableB tableB;


@Embeddable
public class TableBPK implements Serializable {
//default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(name="col_a")
private String colA;

@Column(name="col_b")
private String colB;

@Column(name="col_c")
private String colC;


@Entity
@Table(name="table_b")
public class TableB implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private TableBPK id;

@Column(name="col_ex_d")
private Integer colExD;

@Column(name="col_ex_e")
private String colExE;

@Column(name="col_ex_f")
private Boolean colExF;

//bi-directional one-to-one association to TableA
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns({
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="col_a", referencedColumnName="col_a"),
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="col_b", referencedColumnName="col_b"),
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="col_c", referencedColumnName="col_c")
    })
private TableA tableA;
```

If you like to test on your local: Project has a liquibase configuration to create tables, even inserting example data itself (`composite-persistence/src/main/liquibase`). You can check `changelog.xml` file for creation of tables and primary&foreign keys. But I did not include a connection properties file in the package. if you want to run the project on your local, i can try to help with setting of environment. To test just call the servlet on a browser after deployment

```
/composite-web/Composite?myKey=a1
```

If you like to test with eclipselink just activate provider and properties on `composite-persistence/src/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml` (they are commented out to use default JPA provider of Jboss: Hibernate; you need to configure eclipselink module on Jboss server). The setting of entities work with eclipselink by the way.

Comment: try `TableA_.tableB.id` in the `query.where` line.

Comment: @acdcjunior, I have changed where condition as suggested: `query.where(cb.equal(aEntity.get(TableA_.tableB).get(TableB_.id).get(TableBPK_.colA), key));` but result is same `org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class org.test.hibernate.persistence.entity.TableB. Expected: class org.test.hibernate.persistence.entity.TableBPK, got class org.test.hibernate.persistence.entity.TableAPK`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `TableAPK` and `TableBPK` are equal (have the exact same structure), you can delete one and use the other one everywhere.

I mean: delete `TableBPK`, rename `TableAPK` do `TablePK` and use it everywhere.

Making `TableA` like then:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table_a")
public class TableA implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private TablePK id; //<- this line changed from TableAPK to TablePK
...
```

And `TableB`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table_b")
public class TableB implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private TablePK id; //<- this line changed from TableBPK to TablePK
```